# Airflow plugins, RBAC enabled Blueprint not working

Tags: flask, airflow

We had our Airflow custom UI based on this [link](https://tech.marksblogg.com/install-and-configure-apache-airflow.html) and it was working fine with Airflow 1.9.0. 
Following this we upgraded to 1.10.1 and also enabled RBAC. Our custom UI stopped coming after this.

We followed this explanation [note-on-role-based-views](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html?highlight=plugins#note-on-role-based-views) and tried to use our old UI templates with appbuilder_views. On the using the TestAppBuilderBaseView from /tests/plugins/test_plugin.py,

```
class TestAppBuilderBaseView(AppBuilderBaseView):
@expose("/")
def test(self):
    return self.render("test_plugin/test.html", content="Hello galaxy!")
```

we get the menu and the link, but on clicking we get the error

> object has no attribute 'render'

On changing this to

```
return self.render_template("test_plugin/test.html",content="Hello galaxy!")
```

we get the error

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: test_plugin/test.html

I have tried all possible combination placing the templates folder and the html file, but still its the same error.

I do find some forums telling to enable debug on Blueprint. but I am not aware on how you can do that with Airflow

Any guidance on this please?.
Thanks in Advance
 
Jeenson

Comment: Can anyone answer this please. I am also stuck with the same error..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version 1.10.0 when released had a bug that was not installing the plugins correctly in the new UI. This was fixed in the version 1.10.1, but the code example for plugins in Airflow documentation is broken.

I wrote a sample project to make the integration work, you can check it here: https://github.com/felipegasparini/airflow_plugin_rbac_test

But in short, you need to:

1. Import the BaseView from appbuilder correctly using:

   from flask_appbuilder import BaseView as AppBuilderBaseView
2. Change the name of the method 'test' to 'list'
3. Set the template_folder property to point to where your templates are.

Something like this:

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from flask_appbuilder import BaseView as AppBuilderBaseView

class TestAppBuilderBaseView(AppBuilderBaseView):

    template_folder = '/root/airflow/plugins/test_plugin/templates'

    @expose("/")
    def list(self):
        return self.render_template("test.html", content="Hello galaxy!")

v_appbuilder_view = TestAppBuilderBaseView()
v_appbuilder_package = {"name": "Test View",
                        "category": "Test Plugin",
                        "view": v_appbuilder_view}

# Defining the plugin class
class AirflowTestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "test_plugin"
    # operators = [PluginOperator]
    # sensors = [PluginSensorOperator]
    # hooks = [PluginHook]
    # executors = [PluginExecutor]
    # macros = [plugin_macro]
    # admin_views = [v]
    # flask_blueprints = [bp]
    # menu_links = [ml]
    appbuilder_views = [v_appbuilder_package]
    # appbuilder_menu_items = [appbuilder_mitem]
```

Comment: Thanks @fgasparini will try this out and let you know

Comment: This will fail for packaged plugins that are not inside plugins/ dir. We cannot determine the absolute path to template dir. In such case registering a blueprint is working

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced the same issue. 
After including template folder in blueprint its picking up the correct folder and here is my working example.

Please keep the folder structure like below

```
Plugin
|_test_plugin
   |_templates
      |_test.html
   test_plugin.py
```

### test_plugin.py

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose
from flask_admin.base import MenuLink

class TestView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def test(self):        
        return self.render("test.html", content="Hello galaxy!")
v = TestView(category="Test Plugin", name="Test View")

blue_print_ = Blueprint("test_plugin",
                        __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

class AirflowTestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "MenuLinks"
    # operators = []
    flask_blueprints = [blue_print_]
    # hooks = []
    # executors = []
    admin_views = [v]    
    #appbuilder_views = [v_appbuilder_package]
```

Answer (score 0):

fgasparini's answer is correct, but I also need to enable the RBAC setting

```
rbac = True
```

in `airflow.cfg` in order for `flask_appbuilder` to work with airflow, otherwise the menu won't show up.